# Compile Error Label Not Defined

Tags: vba, excel

Please help me understand why I'm receiving this error and what I can fix for the code to run properly. I believe it has something to do with the Graphs section. Thanks in advance!

```
Sub LocationAdjust()

    Dim Facility As String
    On Error GoTo Errorcatch

    Facility = "B1"

    If Facility = Aberdeen Then

    'Stoplight Ratings - Works'
    Range("D53:M53").ClearContents
    Range("D54:M54").ClearContents
    Range("D54:M54").ClearFormats
    Range("D133:M133").ClearContents
    Range("D134:M134").ClearContents
    Range("D134:M134").ClearFormats
    Range("C230:L230").ClearContents
    Range("C231:L231").ClearContents
    Range("C231:L231").ClearFormats

    'Statistics Tables - Works'
    Range("C215:F224").ClearContents
    Range("C215:F224").ClearFormats
    Range("G295:J304").ClearContents
    Range("G295:J304").ClearFormats

    'Graphs - Need to fix'

    Dim cht As Chart

    Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 3").Chart

    'Remove Chart Series
    cht.SeriesCollection(2).Delete
    cht.SeriesCollection(3).Delete
    cht.SeriesCollection(4).Delete
    cht.SeriesCollection(5).Delete
    cht.SeriesCollection(6).Delete
    cht.SeriesCollection(7).Delete
    cht.SeriesCollection(8).Delete
    cht.SeriesCollection(9).Delete
    cht.SeriesCollection(10).Delete

    End If

End Sub
Exit Sub

Error Catch:
MsgBox Err.Description
```

Comment: You have `GoTo Errorcatch` but then `Error Catch:`. Remove the space in the latter. Also, `End Sub` needs to be the last line.

Comment: Put `End Sub` at the very end, after the error catch msgbox in addition to making ErrorCatch not have a space in it..

Answer (score 0):

The end of your code should look more like this:

```
Exit Sub

ErrorCatch:
MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub
```

`End Sub` should be the last line. If it's not, then anything after it is not included in the routine's definition.

Answer (score 0):

Facility cannot be *B1* and *Aberdeen* at the same time. I believe you want the text value from Range("B1") compared to the string "Aberdeen".

```
Facility = Range("B1").Value

If Facility = "Aberdeen" Then
```

btw, that will be a case-sensitive comparison.

Another point should be made regarding your SeriesCollection deletions. When you delete like this,

```
'Remove Chart Series
cht.SeriesCollection(2).Delete
```

Then SeriesCollection(3) becomes SeriesCollection(2) and so on. Your next operation is to,

```
cht.SeriesCollection(3).Delete
```

But that is actually the original SeriesCollection(4) so you've skipped over the original SeriesCollection(3) and you are going to run out of SeriesCollections before you hit SeriesCollection(10). Try this,

```
do while cht.SeriesCollection.count > 1
    cht.SeriesCollection(2).Delete
loop
```

That will keep deleting until there is only 1 left.